# Why can't Perl see this directory?

Tags: perl

I have this directory structure:

```
$ ls -F
analyze/
data.pl
input.pl
logminer.txt
logSearch.pl
readFormat.pl
Version Notes.txt
datadump.pl
format/
logminer.pl
logs/
properties.txt
unzip.exe
```

I run:

```
perl -e 'if (!(-d analyze)){ print "poo\n"}'
```

and it prints `poo`.

What is missing here? I have done tests like this earlier and it would correctly identify that the directory exists. Why not this directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -e 'if (!(-d "analyze")){ print "poo\n"}'
                  ^--     ^---
```

missing quotes?

edit: changed to double quotes - forgot this was for command-line perl

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and it still prints...really strange behavior!

Comment: I was just gonna say that if you use single quotes to quote the code, you can't use them as quotes inside the code. `q` should also work. ;-)

Comment: @ikegami: yes, but this is on the command line, so my single quote actually terminated the perl code.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade: mybad, forgot it was for CLI perl. I've updated the answer with the proper quoting now.

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
-d analyze
```

means "check if the file *handle* `anaylyze` is a directory handle". You want

```
-d 'analyze'
```

Now, you say you still get the problem by doing that, so check what error you're getting.

```
my $rv = -d 'analyze';
die "stat: $!" if !defined($rv);
die "Not a dir" if !$rv;
```

`-d` is just a thin wrapper around `stat(2)`, so it's not *Perl* that "can't see", it's the system.

The most common errors:

- The current work directory isn't what you think it is. (Many people assume it's always the directory in which the script resides.)
- The file name has trailing whitespace, especially a newline. (That's not likely to be the case here.)

Comment: So, that is to say, where I to make this check inside of a .pl instead of in command line, single quoting would be the correct way?

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade, To Perl, there is no difference between `'anaylyze'` and `"analyze"` and `"\x61nalyze"`. Use the one you want. Of course, `'\x61nalyze'` would be different. Double-quotes interpolate and have many escape sequences, while only `\\ ` and `\'` are special in single quotes.